# C#: Timestamp being truncated?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Running the command text in MySQL workbench returns `2023-04-09 11:37:05.508`

The code below, truncated it to: `2023-04-09 11:37:05`. I would like to know why?

Column is defined as `datetime(3)`.

Reproduce with sample code below:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

connection.Open();

const string commandText = @"SELECT logged_at FROM logs WHERE application_id = @id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 3;

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["logged_at"].ToString());
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: The ToString() is default display is truncating.  Add you on custom format ToString(format) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Use `SELECT CAST(logged_at AS CHAR) AS logged_at ...` and further `Console.WriteLine(reader["logged_at"]);`. In this case the value will be converted to string on the database side (w/o truncation), and client won't alter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `DateTime.ToString()` does extract the DateTime down only to seconds. This means, the underlying value you have is more accurate but not printed. You can check this simply by placing a break point and watch the variables value debugging your application.

To get a more detailed output, you can make use of a [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) like:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)reader["logged_at"];
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```